# Do we use 3NF to build Data Marts in Kimball's Data Warehouse Approach?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmGEY.png)

I was looking at some images which explains Ralph Kimball architecture and some of them shows data marts are in 3NF. But some articles shows star schema(denormalized) is used in Kimball's approach. Which one is true?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It looks like you have the answer from the text in the question. Yes, the image is misleading and not descriptive of Kimball's approach.

Comment: The image is misleading. Also, we shouldn't mix data marts and star schema together to reach to any conclusion. Both are separate things.